# ASP.Net Web API - scaling large number of write operations

Tags: asp.net-web-api, redis, rabbitmq, message-queue, scalability

I am working on a project using ASP.Net Web API that will be receiving a large number of POST operations where I will need to write many successive / simultaneous records to the DB. I don't have an exact number per second so this is more of a conceptual design question.

I am thinking of having either a standard message queue (RabbitMQ, etc) or an in-memory data store such as Redis to handle the initial intake of the data and then persisting that data to the disk via another process (or even a built in one of the queue mechanism has one).

I know I could also use threading to improve performance of the API.

Does anyone have any suggestions as far as which message queues or memory storage to look at or even just architectural recommendations?

Thanks for any and all help everyone.

-c

Comment: Will your DB be able to handle all the writes? Because using all this middle ware will make your web application scale, but it still means the same load on your DB. What db are we speaking about? Your asp.net web api can be pretty fast with just using async/await.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The databas will be ms sql for now. Luckily the amount of data being posted is relatively small. I'll go the async / await route to begin with. I've been reading about the performance improvements that alone can provide. Can you think of any things to watch out for going that route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using all this middle ware will make your web application scale, but it still means the same load on your DB. Your asp.net web api can be pretty fast with just using async/await. On async/await you just need to be carefully to do them all the way down - from controller to database and external requests - don't mix them with Tasks because you will end up with deadlocks.
And don't you threading because you will consume applications threads and this way it will not be able to scale - leave the threads to be used by the ASP.NET Web API.